# How do we find the range of composite functions like the one below?

Tags: functions

The functions f and g are defined by

## fx

4
x
− 2 for x > 0,

## gx

4/
5x + 2
for x ≥ 0.
(i) Find and simplify an expression for fgx
and state the range of fg.

Comment: `Find ... an expression for f(g(x))` Did you try this, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(g(x))=4(\frac{4}{5x+2})-2 \text{ for }x\geq0$$

You typed the question but showed no effort. Show more effort. Get the rest of the answer.

Comment: Did it. Thans !

Comment: If you find the answer useful. You may accept it @Asad